# UIButton UIControlEventTouchUpInside does not fire, but UIControlEventTouchDown does fire

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I am implementing `UIButton` and my `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event does not fire, even though `UIControlEventTouchDown` does fire.

```
UIButton *btnClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSString *filePathImage = @"img.png";
NSString *filePathImageTap = @"img-tap.png";
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePathImage];
UIImage *buttonImageTap = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePathImageTap];
[btnClose setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnClose setImage:buttonImageTap forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnClose setImage:buttonImageTap forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];      
[btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[self.view addSubview:btnClose];
```

Comment: Please post the implementation of `-close:`. I suspect that your method doesn't actually take an argument, but by adding the colon in your selector, the wrong message is being sent.

Comment: Mark it does take an argument, same method work when using UIControlEventTouchDown
- (void) close:(id)sender
{
}

Comment: Where have you specified a target and action for the `UIControlEventTouchDown` control event?

Comment: I just tried testing by replacing UIControlEventTouchDown instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: Ok Guys,
I fixed the issue my stupidity I had UITapGestureRecognizer capturing all the events on the view. I missed it. Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: @iosdevnyc you should put this comment as an answer, it helped me.  Doing same thing....durrrr moment.

Comment: @iosdevnyc: Please post your solution as answer and mark it as accepted in order to help others easier.

Answer (score 3):

I have an assumption why it doesn't take the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`:

I had two "BannerView" (Advertisement) in two different ViewControllers. In one it just worked fine in the other I saw how the `UIButton` was touched and the second image (darker) appeared. But the selector was not hit. Then I realized, that the `Up`-Event was absorbt by a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` from a `UIImageView` below. Some `Recognizer` compete against each other. I searched for an overview to see witch ones these are, but found nothing.

Another solution:
If you see that the ButtonState doesn't change u have to look if you have a View over your Button.